# Question from the write up of a solution concerning integration of greatest integer function.

Tags: integration, analysis

[image]

I have a quick question about the written solution of the question attched in the image. In the beginning of the solution of the second line, it states:  "We observe that for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$, if $nt$ is not an integer,..."

Question: Why consider $t$ only in between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ inclusive and what happen for $t$ between $\frac{1}{2} \leq t < 1$?  Also, how did the author get $(-1)^{[nt]}=(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{[n(1-t)]}$

Comment: @OliverDiaz can I ask, how you get [n-nr]=n-r-1?  I always thought with the greatest integer function, I always have to go back to the definition where $[x]\leq x < [x]+1$, so with $[nt]$, I have to use the the inequality $[nt]< nt < [(t(n+1)]-1<[t(n+1)]$

Comment: $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$, that is $n\leq x<n+1$, it is also known as the floor function. A related function is $\lceil x\rceil =\lfloor x\rfloor +1$, which is the ceiling function.

Comment: @OliverDiaz how is it that $(-1)^{-r}=(-1)^{[nt]}$ when r is in between 0 and 1.  What if [nt] is odd, then we have $(-1)^{[nt]}=-1$, then $(-1)^{-r}$ would be $\frac{1}{i}$

Comment: There is a typo in my comment, it should have been $k$ not $r$, sorry. I just fixed it. Is this clear now?

Comment: Suppose $\lfloor nt\rfloor =k$ and $nt\not\in\mathbb{N}$, then $nt=k+r$ where $0<r<1$. Then $n-nt=n-k-r=(n-k-1)+(1-r)$, that is, $\lfloor n-nt\rfloor =n-k-1$. Consequently
$$n+1+\lfloor n-nt\rfloor = n+1+n-k-1=2n-k$$
Hence 
$$(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{\lfloor n-nt\rfloor}=(-1)^{-k}=(-1)^{k}=(-1)^{\lfloor nt\rfloor}$$

Comment: @OliverDiaz do you mean the following, since $n-nt=n-k-r$ and r is in between 0 and 1.  So we have $\lceil n-k-r\rceil=\lceil n-k\rceil - 1=  \lfloor n - k \rfloor = n - k - 1$?

Comment: Indeed, $n-nt=n-k-r=n=k-1+(1-r)$. Notice that $0<1-r<1$; hence $\lfloor n-nt\rfloor - n-k-1$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz thank you so much. That integration question, I got it from a book on an index of math problem from the American Mathematical monthly.  It is one of the integration questions where you can't really just crank out pages and pages of algebra to arrive at the finish line.

Comment: It is a tricky one, I was banging my head around it  for a few hours trying to come up with a smart decomposition of the unit interval. But, at the and I jut read the solution.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I read the entire solution, when i first posted this question, I had like a list of ten points I did not understand.  I widdle down to one which is the first point I was not able to get.  Integer functions is one of those functions where if you can't go back to play with the inequality based on the definition, you just pray some sort of algebraic trick will come and save the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lfloor nt\rfloor =k$ and $nt\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $nt=k+r$ where $0<r<1$. Then $n-nt=n-k-r=(n-k-1)+(1-r)$, that is, $\lfloor n-nt\rfloor =n-k-1$. Consequently
$$n+1+\lfloor n-nt\rfloor = n+1+n-k-1=2n-k$$
Hence
$$(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{\lfloor n-nt\rfloor}=(-1)^{-k}=(-1)^{k}=(-1)^{\lfloor nt\rfloor}$$

Regarding your first question, once you now what happened for $0\leq t\leq\frac12$,  when $nt\notin\mathbb{Z}$, then you also know what happens for $\frac12\leq s\leq 1$ when $ns\notin\mathbb{Z}$, just take $t=1-s$ and notice that $0\leq t\leq\frac12$ and $nt=n-ns\notin\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: that formula is one strange one in the sense the author just pull it out of thin air seems like.

Comment: He might have worked it out after some time attacking the problem. That seems to be the secret sauce in his argument.

Comment: ah okay okay, thank you so very much again.  :)