# Question about proof write up to an exercise concerning extension field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to ask if someone can check the proof of the following short question about extension field in field theory.  I know the question is a bit basic, i just want to make sure if the way I write out the proof is written correctly and precisely.

Definition: Let $K$ be extension field of $F$ and $u \in K$.  Let $F(u)$ denote the intersection of all subfields of $K$ that contain both $F$ and $u$.

Question: If $u \in K$, prove that $F(u^2) \subset F(u)$

Proof: Suppose $u^2\in F(u^2)$ and $K$ is an extension field of $F$ and $u \in K$ then $K \supseteq F$ and $F(u)$ is a subfield of $K$ that contains both $F$ and $u$.  $F(u)$ being a subfield and hence a field implies that $u^2 \in F(u)$.  This means that $F(u^2) \subset F(u)$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not write more than necessary:

Given $u \in K$, since $F(u)$ is a subfield of $K$ (in particular, is closed under multiplication), we have that $u \in F(u)$ implies $u^2 \in F(u)$. Thus, $F(u)$ is a subfield of $K$ containing both $F$ and $u^2$, but $F(u^2)$ is the least subfield of $K$ with that properties, so $F(u^2) \subseteq F(u)$.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  can you clarify for me how I could be sure that $F(u^2)$ is a subfield smaller than $F(u)$. I was trying to justify that particular aspect of logical reasoning with my verbose argument.

Comment: Sure. Recall that if $\mathcal A$ is a set of sets, then $\bigcap \mathcal A \subseteq A$ for each $A \in \mathcal A$. Then note that $F(u)$ is an element of $\mathcal A := \{L \subseteq K : \textrm{$L$ is a subfield of $K$ containing both $F$ and $u^2$}\}$, and by definition $F(u^2) = \bigcap \mathcal A$.

Comment: does that mean when we say $u^2 \in F(u)$, it means $F(u)$ is a subfield containing both $F$ and $u^2$ and hene $F(u^2)$ is the intersection of all the subfields $F(u)$ of $K$  containing both $F$ and $u^2$?

Comment: I also posted another question about solution to a problem.  I just some quick question about greatest integer function identities that is stumping me and I am wondering if you can take a quick look at it. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209614/question-from-the-write-up-of-a-solution-concerning-integration-of-greatest-inte) Thank you.

Comment: @SethMai Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by "$F(u^2)$ is in the intersection of all subfields $F(u)$ of $K$ containing both $F$ and $u^2$".

Comment: I meant $F(u^2)$ is an element of the intersection of all subfields $F(u)$ of K, where each $F(u)$ contains both $F$ and $u^2$.  Is that correct phrasing?